# Window scrolls down when I open a new accordion tab (pure javascript and css)

Tags: javascript, accordion

I have a pure javascript and css accordion with a large amount of text. When I open a new tab, I’m left at the bottom of the page and I  have to scroll up to the begining of the accordion item in order to be able to read the content.

I’d like to scroll to top of the specific active panel that is open.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Html code:**

**CSS:**

**Javascript code:**

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion__wrapper__item");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    var coursePanel = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "accordion__wrapper__panel"
    );
    var courseAccordion = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "accordion__wrapper__item"
    );
    var courseAccordionActive = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "accordion__wrapper__item active"
    );

    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;

      this.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      for (var ii = 0; ii < courseAccordionActive.length; ii++) {
        courseAccordionActive[ii].classList.remove("active");
      }

      for (var iii = 0; iii < coursePanel.length; iii++) {
        this.classList.remove("active");
        coursePanel[iii].style.maxHeight = null;
      }

      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";

      this.classList.add("active");
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.accordion__wrapper {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  &__intro {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    color: black;
  }
}

button.accordion__wrapper__item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

button.accordion__wrapper__item:before {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

button.accordion__wrapper__item.active:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.accordion__wrapper__panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "roboto";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  p {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    a {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}

.accordion-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgb(198, 198, 198);
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.accordion-line:last-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.accordion__link {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 32pxff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  &--top {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
  &__img {
    margin-right: -16px;
    &--top {
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
  }
  &__text {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.accordion__dot {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start;
  &__span {
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 32pxg;
  }
  &__p {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    font-weight: 200;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
}

.accordion__wrapper__panel {
  ul {
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-width: 50%;
    li {
      font-weight: 200;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .accordion__wrapper__panel {
    p {
      max-width: 70% !important;
    }
    ul {
      max-width: 70% !important;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
  .panel {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .accordion-p {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .accordion__wrapper__panel {
    ul {
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
  .accordion__wrapper {
    margin-top: 48px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    &__intro {
      margin-bottom: 48px;
    }
    &__panel {
      p {
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .accordion__wrapper {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
  }
  .accordion {
    padding: 0;
    &:before {
      margin-right: 24px;
    }
  }
  .accordion-p {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .accordion__dot__span {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .accordion__dot__p {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="accordion__wrapper">

  <p class="accordion__wrapper__intro">Im einzelnen geht es beim Immobilienkauf um Folgendes:</p>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">1. Kaufgegenstand</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Zur <a href="">Vorbereitung</a> des Kaufvertrages und der Einsichtnahme in das Grundbuch benötigen wir von Ihnen Angaben zum Grundstück oder der Wohnung, insbesondere zum Grundbuchblatt, auf welchem das Grundstück verzeichnet ist, oder wo es belegen
      ist. Auch sollten Sie uns von sich aus rechtzeitig Besonderheiten des Kaufobjekts mitteilen, damit wir diese individuell im Vertragstext berücksichtigen können. Hierzu zählen natürlich auch etwaige Ihnen bekannte Mängel oder von einer Partei versprochene
      Zusatzleistungen.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">2. Belastungen des Grundstücks</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Häufig sind Grundstücke mit den unterschiedlichsten Rechten belastet, wie z. B. Grundschulden oder Hypotheken, Dienstbarkeiten oder Reallasten, aber auch Wohnrechten, Nacherbenvermerken oder Zwangsvollstreckungsvermerken. Die meisten Belastungen sind
      aus dem Grundbuch erkennbar. In der Regel verpflichtet sich der Verkäufer, die auf dem Grundstück ruhenden Hypotheken und Grundschulden zu löschen, sei es durch Rückzahlung des gesicherten Kredits oder durch Verpfändung eines anderen Grundstücks.
      <br>
      <br> Sofern Sie den Kaufpreis durch Kreditaufnahme finanzieren, muss zugunsten Ihrer Bank eine Grundschuld (siehe auch Grundpfandrechte) bestellt werden.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">3. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>Beim Immobilienkaufvertrag ist die Sicherung des Leistungsaustausches von besonderer Bedeutung. Der Verkäufer soll das Eigentum nur übertragen, wenn die Kaufpreiszahlung gesichert ist; der Käufer will den Kaufpreis erst zahlen, wenn der Eigentumswechsel
      gesichert ist. Deshalb sieht der Kaufvertrag regelmäßig vor, dass der Kaufpreis erst nach Vorliegen bestimmter Voraussetzungen an den Verkäufer gezahlt werden soll. Hierzu zählen in der Regel:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>das Vorliegen aller erforderlichen Genehmigungen oder Zustimmungserklärungen, das Vorliegen aller erforderlichen Genehmigungen oder Zustimmungserklärungen,</li>
      <li>das Vorliegen aller erforderlichen Genehmigungen oder Zustimmungserklärungen,</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Ein geeignetes Mittel zur Gewährleistung einer Zug-um-Zug-Abwicklung ist die Kaufpreiszahlung über ein Notaranderkonto.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">4. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Im Kaufvertrag ist der Stichtag für den wirtschaftlichen Übergang des Grundstücks auf den Käufer festzulegen. Von diesem Zeitpunkt an kann der Käufer das Grundstück in Besitz nehmen. Mieterträge stehen von nun an dem Käufer zu, der ab dem Stichtag allerdings
      auch die Kosten und Lasten des Grundstücks (Müll- und Abwassergebühren, Grundsteuer etc.) zu tragen hat. Der wirtschaftliche Übergang erfolgt in der Regel mit der vollständigen Kaufpreiszahlung.
      <br>
      <br> Ist die Übergabe des Kaufgegenstandes Voraussetzung für die Auszahlung des Kaufpreises vom Notaranderkonto, so ist dem Notar die erfolgte Übergabe unverzüglich nachzuweisen. In der Regel geschieht dies durch Übersendung eines bei Übergabe von
      beiden Vertragsparteien unterzeichneten Übergabeprotokolls.
    </p>
    <div class="accordion__link">
      <img class="accordion__link__img" src="assets/pdf-blue.svg" alt="pdf" />
      <p class="accordion__link__text">Download Muster Übergabeprotokoll (PDF)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">5. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Liegen dem Notar sämtliche für die Eigentumsumschreibung erforderlichen Unterlagen vor und sind die ihm von Gläubigern aufgegebenen Treuhandauflagen erfüllbar, wird er beim Grundbuchamt die Eigentumsumschreibung beantragen, vorausgesetzt natürlich, dass
      der Kaufpreis bezahlt ist. Auf diese Weise hat der Verkäufer die Sicherheit, das Eigentum am Kaufgegenstand erst nach Erhalt des vertraglich vereinbarten Kaufpreises zu verlieren.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">6. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Um einen ersten Vertragsentwurf zu fertigen, benötigen wir von Ihnen eine Angabe zu den Parteien und dem Objekt! Füllen Sie den Vorbereitungsbogen aus und schicken Sie ihn an uns zurück. Wir werden uns sodann bei Ihnen melden.
    </p>
    <div class="accordion__link">
      <img class="accordion__link__img" src="assets/pdf-blue.svg" alt="pdf" />
      <p class="accordion__link__text">Download Vorbereitungsbogen (PDF)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">7. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <div class="accordion__link">
      <img class="accordion__link__img" src="assets/pdf-blue.svg" alt="pdf" />
      <p class="accordion__link__text">Glossar zu Grundstücks- und Hauskaufverträgen (PDF)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__link">
      <img class="accordion__link__img" src="assets/pdf-blue.svg" alt="pdf" />
      <p class="accordion__link__text">Merkblatt zum Kauf eines gebrauchten Hauses (PDF)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

</section>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.  We would like to help you,  but your code is missing a bunch of the required parts to make the  accordian work.  Take a look at: [How to provide a minimal reproducable example][1] and also this page: [How to ask a good question][2] to learn about how to ask a question that we can answer.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you for your advice @mike510a. I added the css which was missing and I'm gonna check the links from your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `item.scrollIntoView()`  along with added an event parameter to your onclick function

`onclick = function(e)`

where e stands for event
then adding `e.target.scrollIntoView()` will work anywhere in the onclick function()

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion__wrapper__item");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {

  // change to function(e)
  acc[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    var coursePanel = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "accordion__wrapper__panel"
    );
    var courseAccordion = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "accordion__wrapper__item"
    );
    var courseAccordionActive = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "accordion__wrapper__item active"
    );

    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;

      this.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      for (var ii = 0; ii < courseAccordionActive.length; ii++) {
        courseAccordionActive[ii].classList.remove("active");
      }

      for (var iii = 0; iii < coursePanel.length; iii++) {
        this.classList.remove("active");
        coursePanel[iii].style.maxHeight = null;
      }

      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";

      this.classList.add("active");
      // added scrollIntoView()

      e.target.scrollIntoView()




    }
  };
}
```

```css
.accordion__wrapper {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  &__intro {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    color: black;
  }
}

button.accordion__wrapper__item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

button.accordion__wrapper__item:before {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

button.accordion__wrapper__item.active:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.accordion__wrapper__panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "roboto";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  p {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    a {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}

.accordion-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgb(198, 198, 198);
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.accordion-line:last-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.accordion__link {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 32pxff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  &--top {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
  &__img {
    margin-right: -16px;
    &--top {
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
  }
  &__text {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.accordion__dot {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start;
  &__span {
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 32pxg;
  }
  &__p {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    font-weight: 200;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
}

.accordion__wrapper__panel {
  ul {
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-width: 50%;
    li {
      font-weight: 200;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .accordion__wrapper__panel {
    p {
      max-width: 70% !important;
    }
    ul {
      max-width: 70% !important;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
  .panel {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .accordion-p {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .accordion__wrapper__panel {
    ul {
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
  .accordion__wrapper {
    margin-top: 48px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    &__intro {
      margin-bottom: 48px;
    }
    &__panel {
      p {
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .accordion__wrapper {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
  }
  .accordion {
    padding: 0;
    &:before {
      margin-right: 24px;
    }
  }
  .accordion-p {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .accordion__dot__span {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .accordion__dot__p {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="accordion__wrapper">

  <p class="accordion__wrapper__intro">Im einzelnen geht es beim Immobilienkauf um Folgendes:</p>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">1. Kaufgegenstand</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Zur <a href="">Vorbereitung</a> des Kaufvertrages und der Einsichtnahme in das Grundbuch benötigen wir von Ihnen Angaben zum Grundstück oder der Wohnung, insbesondere zum Grundbuchblatt, auf welchem das Grundstück verzeichnet ist, oder wo es belegen
      ist. Auch sollten Sie uns von sich aus rechtzeitig Besonderheiten des Kaufobjekts mitteilen, damit wir diese individuell im Vertragstext berücksichtigen können. Hierzu zählen natürlich auch etwaige Ihnen bekannte Mängel oder von einer Partei versprochene
      Zusatzleistungen.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">2. Belastungen des Grundstücks</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Häufig sind Grundstücke mit den unterschiedlichsten Rechten belastet, wie z. B. Grundschulden oder Hypotheken, Dienstbarkeiten oder Reallasten, aber auch Wohnrechten, Nacherbenvermerken oder Zwangsvollstreckungsvermerken. Die meisten Belastungen sind
      aus dem Grundbuch erkennbar. In der Regel verpflichtet sich der Verkäufer, die auf dem Grundstück ruhenden Hypotheken und Grundschulden zu löschen, sei es durch Rückzahlung des gesicherten Kredits oder durch Verpfändung eines anderen Grundstücks.
      <br>
      <br> Sofern Sie den Kaufpreis durch Kreditaufnahme finanzieren, muss zugunsten Ihrer Bank eine Grundschuld (siehe auch Grundpfandrechte) bestellt werden.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">3. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>Beim Immobilienkaufvertrag ist die Sicherung des Leistungsaustausches von besonderer Bedeutung. Der Verkäufer soll das Eigentum nur übertragen, wenn die Kaufpreiszahlung gesichert ist; der Käufer will den Kaufpreis erst zahlen, wenn der Eigentumswechsel
      gesichert ist. Deshalb sieht der Kaufvertrag regelmäßig vor, dass der Kaufpreis erst nach Vorliegen bestimmter Voraussetzungen an den Verkäufer gezahlt werden soll. Hierzu zählen in der Regel:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>das Vorliegen aller erforderlichen Genehmigungen oder Zustimmungserklärungen, das Vorliegen aller erforderlichen Genehmigungen oder Zustimmungserklärungen,</li>
      <li>das Vorliegen aller erforderlichen Genehmigungen oder Zustimmungserklärungen,</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Ein geeignetes Mittel zur Gewährleistung einer Zug-um-Zug-Abwicklung ist die Kaufpreiszahlung über ein Notaranderkonto.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">4. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Im Kaufvertrag ist der Stichtag für den wirtschaftlichen Übergang des Grundstücks auf den Käufer festzulegen. Von diesem Zeitpunkt an kann der Käufer das Grundstück in Besitz nehmen. Mieterträge stehen von nun an dem Käufer zu, der ab dem Stichtag allerdings
      auch die Kosten und Lasten des Grundstücks (Müll- und Abwassergebühren, Grundsteuer etc.) zu tragen hat. Der wirtschaftliche Übergang erfolgt in der Regel mit der vollständigen Kaufpreiszahlung.
      <br>
      <br> Ist die Übergabe des Kaufgegenstandes Voraussetzung für die Auszahlung des Kaufpreises vom Notaranderkonto, so ist dem Notar die erfolgte Übergabe unverzüglich nachzuweisen. In der Regel geschieht dies durch Übersendung eines bei Übergabe von
      beiden Vertragsparteien unterzeichneten Übergabeprotokolls.
    </p>
    <div class="accordion__link">
      <img class="accordion__link__img" src="assets/pdf-blue.svg" alt="pdf" />
      <p class="accordion__link__text">Download Muster Übergabeprotokoll (PDF)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">5. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Liegen dem Notar sämtliche für die Eigentumsumschreibung erforderlichen Unterlagen vor und sind die ihm von Gläubigern aufgegebenen Treuhandauflagen erfüllbar, wird er beim Grundbuchamt die Eigentumsumschreibung beantragen, vorausgesetzt natürlich, dass
      der Kaufpreis bezahlt ist. Auf diese Weise hat der Verkäufer die Sicherheit, das Eigentum am Kaufgegenstand erst nach Erhalt des vertraglich vereinbarten Kaufpreises zu verlieren.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">6. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <p>
      Um einen ersten Vertragsentwurf zu fertigen, benötigen wir von Ihnen eine Angabe zu den Parteien und dem Objekt! Füllen Sie den Vorbereitungsbogen aus und schicken Sie ihn an uns zurück. Wir werden uns sodann bei Ihnen melden.
    </p>
    <div class="accordion__link">
      <img class="accordion__link__img" src="assets/pdf-blue.svg" alt="pdf" />
      <p class="accordion__link__text">Download Vorbereitungsbogen (PDF)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

  <button class="accordion__wrapper__item">7. Fälligkeit des Kaufpreises</button>
  <div class="accordion__wrapper__panel">
    <div class="accordion__link">
      <img class="accordion__link__img" src="assets/pdf-blue.svg" alt="pdf" />
      <p class="accordion__link__text">Glossar zu Grundstücks- und Hauskaufverträgen (PDF)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__link">
      <img class="accordion__link__img" src="assets/pdf-blue.svg" alt="pdf" />
      <p class="accordion__link__text">Merkblatt zum Kauf eines gebrauchten Hauses (PDF)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-line"></div>

</section>
```